# Angular add new doc in firestore without list

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am new in angular and firebase, I got a crud operation project which work like below

```
export class EmployeeService {
  employeeList: AngularFireList<any>;
  selectedEmployee: Employee = new Employee();
  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  getData() {
    this.employeeList = this.firebase.list('employees');
    return this.employeeList;
  }

  insertEmployee(empoloyee: Employee) {
    this.employeeList.push({
      name: empoloyee.name,
      position: empoloyee.position,
      office: empoloyee.office,
      salary: empoloyee.salary
    });
  }

  updateEmployee(emp : Employee){
     this.employeeList.update(emp.$key,{
       name : emp.name,
       position : emp.position,
       office : emp.office,
       salary : emp.salary
     })
  }

  deleteEmployee(key : string){
    this.employeeList.remove(key);
  }

}
```

Here as per my understanding to add a new record it add items into list which has been fetched through getData.

Is there possible to add a new doc in collection without fetching list

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching any data.

`this.firebase.list('employees')` is a list binding. Data is only fetched if you add `valueChanges()` and `subscribe()` to this observable created by `valueChanges()`

Comment: Ok, I have just started studying firebase and angular from yesterday only, could you please let me know if this is the recommended way to work with firebase through angular

Comment: I don't think there is a recommended way to access firebase from angular... You can use the native firebase js api, or (like you did) angularfire2. It's not a use this OR the other, you can combine both. [The documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) of angularfire2 should point you in the right direction.